# Sharing Time variable Between two threads

Tags: python, multithreading

Hi i need to create 2 threads one  which repeatedly writes the time of day as an
HH:MM:SS string into a global variable 100 times per second. The second thread will repeatedly read the time of day
string from that variable twice per second and try to display it to screen but code in that thread should ensure the same
string is never written twice in a row. The result is that second thread really displays to screen only once per second. i have tried following code but its not working

```
    import threading
    import time
    c = threading.Condition()
    flag = 0      #shared between Thread_A and Thread_B
    val = ''

class Thread_A(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name

    def run(self):
        global flag
        global val     #made global here
        while True:
            c.acquire()
            if flag == 0:
                time.sleep(0)
                flag = 1
                a=range(1,101)
                for i in a:
                    val=time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime(time.time()))
                c.notify_all()
            else:
                c.wait()
            c.release()


class Thread_B(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name

    def run(self):
        global flag
        global val    #made global here
        while True:
            c.acquire()
            if flag == 1:
                #time.sleep(1)
                flag = 0
                a=range(0,2)
                for i in a:
                    print str(val)
                #val = 20
                c.notify_all()
            else:
                c.wait()
            c.release()


a = Thread_A("myThread_name_A")
b = Thread_B("myThread_name_B")

b.start()
a.start()

a.join()
b.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making this more complicated than it needs to be. You can use a simple `Lock` object to make sure that only one thread can access `val` at a time.

The code below will run on Python 2 or Python 3. To stop it, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
import time
from threading import Thread, Lock

# Rename Python 2's raw_input to input
try:
    input = raw_input
except NameError:
    pass

val = ''
lock = Lock()

def set_time(delay=0.01):
    ''' Write the current time to val '''
    global val
    while True:
        lock.acquire()
        val = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        lock.release()
        time.sleep(delay)

def get_time(delay=0.5):
    ''' Read the current time from val and print
        it if it hasn't been printed already 
    '''
    oldval = ''
    while True:
        lock.acquire()
        if val != oldval:
            print(val)
            oldval = val
        lock.release()
        time.sleep(delay)

# Start the threads
for func in (set_time, get_time):
    t = Thread(target=func)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()

#Wait until we get some input
s = input()
```

**some typical output**

```
02:22:04
02:22:05
02:22:06
02:22:07
02:22:08
```

Comment: @Jeff No worries. The simple way is to make the threads into daemon threads, like my code does: the program will exit when there are only daemon threads left, forcefully terminating any daemon threads that are still running. The main thread in my code is waiting for user input, and as soon as it gets input the main thread will exit, and the daemon threads will be closed.

Comment: @Jeff If threads aren't daemon threads it's a little more complicated because you can't simply kill threads. So you need to set up something that threads can check to see if it's time for them to finish. Eg you can use a `threading.Event` object, and each thread checks the Event to see if it has been set. If it's set, the thread function returns, ending the thread.